# Proper way to check if client has camera

Tags: javascript, camera, client, frontend

I'm building a web app and I need to check if the client has a camera after the user clicks on a button.

I'm currently using this script but it seems not to work on IE.

```
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia || // use the proper vendor prefix
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    navigator.getMedia({video: true}, function() {
      //has camera
    }.bind(this), function() {
      //no camera
    }.bind(this));
```

So what's the best method?

Comment: (FWIW, I wouldn't assign to a property on `navigator`, but it's not likely to be why the above doesn't work on IE.)

Comment: It *might* be the reason it fails; IE is sensitive about weird things. Of course, we'd know for sure if the OP would describe exactly what "not work" means here.

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, I was thinking both of those things as well... :-)

Comment: It doesn't work in IE because IE doesn't support `getUserMedia` (and given the feature is deprecated now, I doubt Edge does, either).

Comment: Sidenote: `navigator.msGetUserMedia` is useless since there is no such property. IE just doesn't support it

Answer (score 3):

Might be problem with:

```
navigator.getUserMedia();
```

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some
>   browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped.
>   Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the
>   compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision.
>   Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

Obtained via:
[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia)

Try: `mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` as a singleton

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(stream) {
  /* use the stream */
})
.catch(function(err) {
  /* handle the error */
});
```

Even if it's not solution you will future-proof your code.

EDIT:

T.J. Crowder pointed out that indeed the deprecated `navigator.getUserMedia();` is listed as not working in IE.

Comment: More to the point, at the bottom of that page it clearly says Internet Explorer has no support for it (deprecated or not).

Comment: Thank you DanteTheSmith! i'll give it a try asap and give you feedback

Comment: I'd like to point out that I used this solution. The problem was NOT solved but I could use the cam on other browsers and handle the error on IE.